# How to run the publish/clickonce build step in Jenkins (VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, clickonce

We have a simple C# solution (VS 2012) that has a publish step/click once wizard - that uses ftp.

I've set up a jenkins build project to build this on SVN trigger. (via MSBuild)

I have NOT been able to get it to build (via MSBuild) the publish/click once installer and upload to my server.  I have looked around and searched but i see no way to do this.  It seems silly that this would be a manual step.

Hopefully this is something simple that I am overlooking.

Any command line app would be suitable - or if there are scripts that can do the same thing that VS2012 does in the wizard that is fine.

Comment: not clear - do you get any errors from Jenkins, or you just can't get the build process started? If you get errors - pls post them.

Comment: I don't get errors - there is just no way that i have found to run the publish project from the command line.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you need this then:

```
msbuild /target:publish
```

see more here: [Building ClickOnce Applications from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx)

this will create "publish" folder - which you have to copy to your server, or network share - whatever you are using for the distribution of your app.

Another problem you have to take care of is to increase the version before the build - you need to update csproj file eventually.

Comment: Yes, however that step does not do the same as what the GUI does - which is actually publish.  And if I have to do both the ftp step and the update version step manually i don't see how this msbuild step is anything like the "publish".  So I guess the answer is - you can't do it - you have to do it manually.  (sorry for the rant)

Comment: i disagree with you - to me the actual upload process is clearly non-MSBUILD task - because it can be network share, Azure storage, blank CDROM... and uploading to FTP is just an extra step after publishing.

Comment: regarding version update - again, to me that's something which should not be done "automatically" anyway - partly because you do want to have your version control system to be updated - so you can track errors to a certain commit etc. But after a quick googling i found this: http://codingeverything.blogspot.ca/2013/05/automatically-increment-minimum.html - looks like a decent solution to me, at least from a quick look.

Comment: look at this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434309/1246870 - looks like version can be a msbuild parameter.

Comment: I understand what you are saying - and I agree - however then the "publish" in the GUI step should not do them either.  There should not be a difference between invoking that step in the GUI vs invoking it from command line.  That is the issue I am having.  Doing it inconsistently is incorrect - on Microsoft's part.  By the way, I upvoted your answer - might set it as the correct one too.