# Winform publish command

Tags: winforms, jenkins, visual-studio-2017, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for a winform application. There is a publish option when I right click on the UI project.

The publish wizard asks for the following information:

Where do you want to publish the application (Location to publish): \\servername\foldername

How will users install the application?: From a UNC path or file share. \\servername\foldername

Will the application be available offline?: No

I am trying to automate this using Jenkins. Is there anyway to run this using MSBuild / MSDeploy? I am looking for command line arguments I need to provide for the above options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run the publish/clickonce build step in Jenkins (VS2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015272/how-to-run-the-publish-clickonce-build-step-in-jenkins-vs2012)

Comment: Just have a look for "ClickOnce". That is the name of the component the publish wizard is from.

Comment: I see, I will have a look. Thank you.