# MSBuild Publish not incrementing the Publish version

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment of a desktop application. In the publishing tab of the build, I've set the "Auto increment on publish". The build for the publish uses the following parameters:

```
/target:publish /property:PublishDir=\\targetdir
```

However, the publish version doesn't increment. Is there a way to automate this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Did you tried this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bda19fb9-c76b-4c9f-a287-4fe8acd23edb/why-dont-the-assembly-version-and-file-version-autoincrement-with-the-publish-version

Comment: Yes - but that it the opposite of my problem

Comment: so your publish version number is not increasing in visual studio? are you using vs 2012 or VS 2010?

Comment: 2012  just updated the question

Comment: if your project file is in the TFS, make sure you got latest version of the project file and it is checked out. Visual studio just trying to update the <ApplicationRevision>1</ApplicationRevision> entry in the project file. May be delete the project file and get latest version may also help.

Comment: Remember, I'm doing this inside a build.  That is, I want the MSBuild command to increment the publish version for me.  This is part of a build, not something local to my PC.

Comment: Sorry. Now I understand your problem I guess. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482360/how-can-i-get-msbuild-to-increment-clickonce-publish-revision-version-number-on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36463/discussion-between-pm-2-and-suresh2)

Comment: Can you provide your normal build log with /verbosity:diag key (very detailed log)

Comment: I can't really, no.  Are you saying that this should work out of the box for clickonce deployment of a desktop app?